# How to config the Docker resources

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, command-line-interface

I am running Docker on a Linux server. By default only 2GB of memory and 0GB of Swap space are allocated. How can I change the memory and swap space in Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/):

> By default, a container has no resource constraints and can use as much of a given resource as the host’s kernel scheduler allows. Docker provides ways to control how much memory, CPU, or block IO a container can use, setting runtime configuration flags of the docker run command

You can use the `-m` or `--memory` option and set it to a desired value depending on your host's available memory.